# Import Stanford nlp Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I'm having trouble using Stanford Lemmatizer. 
As i'm using Intellij IDE, i try to import it via the Dependencies Windows, but i can't access all the class by that way.

Is there a way to import stanford-english-corenlp-models-current.jar & stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar correctly on Intellij?

Comment: what you mean by but i can't access all the class by that way.?

Comment: All those import :

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

Are not found.

I only have import edu.stanford.nlp.demo.*;

Comment: It seems you are using a a wrong jar file. Make sure to get the correct jar

Comment: i have downloaded 4 differents jar files...
The two on the github page : https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP
and 3.6 and 3.7 version here http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Comment: You are currently just importing the models files.  You need to import the jar file with the compiled classes and you need to import the various jars Stanford CoreNLP depends on.  The folder you download at stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP has all the jars you need to import into IntelliJ.  Import all jars in that folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As guys mentioned above,you just import the wrong file

First,download the CoreNLP 3.7.0(beta)
[image]

In the screen shot above,click the red button to download the file,which covers all the things to run the CoreNLP.

Second, right click the module which you want to import jar to to open the "open module settings" pannel ,then you may get a picture like this

[image]

click the green plus button to import all the things

[image]

**Notice:It's the directory I point to you.**

Then click "Apply" and "OK"

This is done.Enjoy it!

Reference:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/
(CoreNLP official web page)

http://jingyan.baidu.com/article/fec7a1e5f79e2b1191b4e74f.html
(how to import jar in Intellij in Chinese)

Comment: Indeed i didn't downloaded the good jar... my bad -_-" Thanks guys, it work perfectly now!

Comment: I couldn't get intellij to add the models jar directly, but adding the whole lib directory worked like magic. Thanks!